# how to make an array of strings that are all the same, in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I'm new to Matlab and can't figure this out from their online doc.

In Basic, I'd do this:

```
for i=1 to 5
   aaa( i ) = "blah"
```

In Matlab, I'm trying this:

```
for x=1:5
    color_operands(x) = 'red';
end
```

...and get an error.

The purpose is to pass `color_operands` to `insertObjectAnnotation()`.

I just tried Troy's suggestion, and still get error:

```
            bboxes_dims = size(bboxes);
            total_boxes = bboxes_dims(1);
            color_opcodes = repmat('Color', total_boxes, 1);
            for box = 1:total_boxes      % for each box
            if <condition>
                    color_operands(box,:) = 'Green';
                else
                    color_operands(box,:) = 'Red';
                      THIS LINE GETS ERROR:
                          "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."
                end
            end
```

Comment: assuming the string doesn't change, just write `for i=1:10 ; aaa(i,:)='blah'; end ` instead...

Comment: A good way to do it `aaa = repmat({'test'},1,3);`